# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor-server-side, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I have a .NET5 Blazor Server application using EFCore5.
I have two entities that have a many-to-many relationship with each other.
Let's call them 'Books' and 'Tags'.
EFCore provides the BookTag join table.

On my page, I have a form that is populated with the book details and has a multi select box for the tags.
I include the tags when I get the book:
`context.Books.Include(x=>x.Tags);`
In debug mode, I see the Book item has several tags. But when I update some details of the book and save the form, calling `context.Books.Update(book);` I get an error because of duplicate keys in the BookTag join table.
It seems EFCore tries to insert entries in that table, but it should do a merge or insert/update.

I've read numerous articles about the many-to-many but all of them just show how to retrieve data. I can't find an example of how to update.

**Edit**:
I'm using the GenericRepository as explained by @carl-franklin in his excellent [BlazorTrain](https://blazortrain.com/) series.

**Edit2**:
Here is some relevant code, I'm now not using the GenericRepo:
**Startup.cs**
`services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")));`

ApplicationDbContext.cs has only the `DbSet`s.

**Book.cs**

```
[Key] 
public string Code { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; } = "";
public virtual ICollection<Tag> TagCollection { get; set; }
```

**Tag.cs**

```
[Key] 
public string Code { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; } = "";
public virtual ICollection<Book> BookCollection { get; set; }
```

**Book.razor.cs**

```
[Inject] private IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextFactory { get; set; }
private ApplicationDbContext context { get; set; }
protected IEnumerable<Book> BookList;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    context = contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    
    BookList = await context.Books.Include(x => x.TagCollection).ToListAsync();
}

private async Task UpdateBook(Book book)
{
    // Called after submitting form
    context.Books.Update(book);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Even if I don't change anything, just update I get the duplicate error:
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_BookTag'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BookTag'`

In UpdateBook() I see the book has tags, as expected. It looks like EFCore is inserting them in the join table without checking if they already exist.

Comment: When you initially read data from database, add `.AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: Thanks Ergis. I'm already doing that. In fact I'm doing it on the context level: `context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;`

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey I've updated my post and added relevant code.

Comment: `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_BookTag'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BookTag'` -- Kinda says it all.  Not sure why you're turning off change tracking; that's what makes all this work.  `Update` does not mean `Upsert` or `Merge`.

Comment: Change tracking was turned off in the GenericRepo I got from BlazorTrain. When in my extracted code I don't turn it off my problems disappear and I can add the tags without errors. As expected. @RobertHarvey If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change tracking must be turned on for this to work.  Otherwise, you have to track the changes yourself; Entity Framework thinks you're adding a new record, but the key is the same as an existing record, which is why you're getting the error.